# C is a set of circles. Each represented as a triple (x y r). Design algorithm that a given set C of n circles determines if any circles intersect

Tags: algorithm, geometry, intersection, pseudocode

Let C be a set of circles each represented as a triple (x; y; r) where x; y is
its center and r is its radius. Design and analyze an algorithm that given a set C of n
circles determines if any of the circles intersect. 
1. Complete pseudo code
2. identify input and the input size, n
3. Identify elementary operation
4. Compute how many times the elementary operation is executed with respect to the input size n
5. Provide Big-O asymptotic characterization for the algorithm's complexity.

I have tried and found ways to find where 2 circles intersect. And found where lines intersect a circle but i am struggling to come up with an algorithm for n number of circles.

Comment: Hint: `for(a in circles){for(b in circles){if (a!=b and intersects(a,b)){...`

Comment: Two circles, of radii `R` and `r`, intersect if their centres are less than `R+r` apart.  Simples, no ?  The problem you have been set doesn't seem to ask where they intersect, that seems to be a complication you have assumed to make a rod for your own back.  Always read the question carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to found an formula that tells you that N circles intersect, just use the one you found for looking if 2 circle intersect, and use for  all the circles. Here it is a basic pseudocode (not sure if it's 100% pseudo-code compliant ;) ).

```
boolean findItersections(Collection C){
    for ( circleA in C ) {
        C.remove(circleA);
        for (circleB in C){
            if (isItersection(circleA, circleB))
                return true;

        }
    }   
}

//elementary operation

boolean isItersection( Circle a, Circle b){

    //distance between centers
    float d = sqrt((a.x -b.x)^2 + (a.y-b.y)^2));

    if(d> a.r+b.r)
        return false;
    else 
        return true;
}
```

Comment: I dind't wrote answers to point 4 and 5 leaving them to you now that you have the algorithm.

Comment: Actually, the isIntersection() function only works for circle regions, not for circles. For two circles at the same center with different radii, the distance between the centers is 0 but these two circles do not intersect. So, the algorithm needs to be adjusted to rule out all interior circles first.